# Cookies Consent Banner for a Multilingual Website

Tags: cookies, popup, jekyll, multilingual

I need to include a Cookies banner to a multilingual website. [Insites](https://cookieconsent.insites.com/) have a pretty neat solution, but I cannot manage to make it pop-up in a different language depending on the language chosen by the user.

My multilingual site uses the following structure: mysite.com (for Spanish), mysite.com/en (for English) and mysite.com/fr (for French), therefore I would need to have 3 different cookie banners pop-up.

Anyone has encountered a similar situation? Or have any idea on how to tackled this  challenge?

Thank you :)